# What is right expression to say "last one play"?

Tags: expressions

My Japanese friends like to say "last one play" in a futsal soccer game which means this game will be over if the ball becomes dead.

"Last one play" sounds a bit strange to me, but English is my second language.

Does "last one play" sound strange to a native English speaker?
What is the right expression to say it?

Comment: Many sports use [*sudden death*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudden_death_(sport)#Board_games) to determine a winner, but that's a little different from the game ending the next time there is a [dead ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_ball).

Comment: One might say, "The next dead ball ends the game," or something similar.

Comment: "last play" sounds good

Comment: what is "futsal"?  Are you speaking of a regular soccer match, or a special version? I thought soccer matches run until time is used up, not until dead ball.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock You are right if it is a real game, but my friends and I just play for fun. This is not a real [futsal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futsal) soccer rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use "last play" or "final play". A sports announcer might say "And the teams square off for the final play of the game."